# JavaFX cannot find symbol when using Color.web

Tags: java, javafx, colors

I am trying to make a simple method that draws a circle based on the origin, radius, and color that I give it.  I can't figure out why I am getting the error Cannot find symbol.  The word web is underlined.  Here is my code:

```
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public void drawCircle(GraphicsContext g, Point origin, int radius,
            boolean centered, boolean filled, String colorValue, int lineThickness) {
        g.setFill(new Color.web("0x57AFFF", 1));
        g.fillOval(origin.x - (radius / 2), origin.y - (radius / 2), radius, radius);
    }
```

Comment: I think that you have missed parenthesis. Try new Color().web ...

Comment: Or remove the "new", web is a static method https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html

Comment: Ahh ok removing new did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the new keyword... 
This is the way to go:

```
Color x = Color.web("0x57AFFF", 1.0);
```